# Android multiple thread algorithm - Is this a good approach?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, algorithm

I would like to know what is the best way to implement a multiple thread algorithm which result must be printed on screen.
To achieve this I am thinking of using an AsyncTask to start the algorithm, and in the doInBackground method to start several threads to make the computation, once all threads are finished, show the result in the onPostExecute method.
Is this a good approach to the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is. How you launch the several threads is another matter. Why not rephrase your question to ask that?

Comment: For launching the threads I will extend Runnable, and start them in an iteration. Do you have any advice on this?

Comment: If you want it on several threads, AsyncTask is a poor choice. From the documentation: "When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution."

Comment: The problem can be resumed if it is a good idea to launch an algorithm which needs several threads to execute, into an asyncTask, this asincTask will execute only once.

Comment: @fadden the OP stated he would be using the `AsyncTask` to _start_ several threads in `doInBackground`. That indicated to me he had elected to defer the overhead of launching several (possibly many?) threads to the background thread.

Comment: @jonagon: I did miss the subtlety; however, there is little overhead involved in starting a thread, so creating an AsyncTask to create threads is redundant. AsyncTask threads run at a lower priority, and threads inherit priority from their parent, so if the goal was to create a collection of low-priority threads then the plan might make sense (if not, then it doesn't). In any event, the thread management classes in `java.util.concurrent` are more generally applicable than AsyncTask.

Comment: @fadden: that helps me, thanks! I thought of using asyncTask because I read it was the best way of communicating the result of a background Thread to the UI Thread. But what you say makes sense, maybe I will have to search the way to do this using Java.util.concurrent.

Comment: @fadden I normally would have agreed, but read something recommending the background launcher approach, somewhere, last week. I didn't need more threads that badly to introduce the extra LOC's and external libraries, thinking Android was designed  this way for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this via asynctask or via handler. they are both feasible.